# Save message to hard drive outlook 2007

Tags: vba, outlook-2007

I need to save message to hard drive with outllok 2007, i need to expor the most recent message, to a folder in the .msg format, can u helpme ?

ty !

pd. using vba ! C:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub saveIt()
    Dim m As MailItem
    Set m = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items.GetLast
    m.SaveAs "c:\temp\" & m.Subject & ".msg", olMSG
End Sub
```